# Will Kafka flapmapValues split the record into multiple records when passing json array object?

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using confluent 5.0.0 version*

I've a JSON array like below :

```
{ 
    "name" : "David,Corral,Babu", 
    "age" : 23
}
```

and by using kafka streams, I want to split the above record into two based on criteria of comma in the value of the "name" key. The output should be something like :

```
{ 
    "name" : "David", 
    "age" : 23
},
{ 
    "name" : "Corral", 
    "age" : 23
},
{
    "name" : "Babu", 
    "age" : 23
 }
```

For this I'm using "flatMapValues". But so far I'm not able to achieve 
    the expected results.

But wanted to check if "flatmapValues" is the correct function to be used 
    for my requirement?

I've used following code:

```
package test;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.*;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KeyValueMapper;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Produced;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class RecordSplliter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("** STARTING RecordSplliter STREAM APP **");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "json-e44nric2315her");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, PersonSeder.class);

        final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        // Consume JSON and enriches it
        KStream<String, Person> source = builder.stream("streams-plaintext-input");

        KStream<String, String> output = source
            .flatMapValues(person -> Arrays.asList(person.getName().split(",")));
        output.to("streams-output");

        final Topology topology = builder.build();
        final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        // Attach shutdown handler to catch control-c
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread("streams-shutdown-hook") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                streams.close();
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });

        try {
            streams.start();
            latch.await();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

During runtime I've got following exception:

```
    08:31:10,822 ERROR 
    org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks  - 
    stream-thread [json-enricher-0f8bc964-40c0-41f2-a724-dfa638923387- 
    StreamThread-1] Failed to process stream task 0_0 due to the following 
    error:
    org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in 
    process. taskId=0_0, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000, topic=streams- 
    plaintext-input, partition=0, offset=0
    at 
 org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:304)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:94)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:409)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.processAndMaybeCommit(StreamThread.java:957)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:832)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:767)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:736)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: A serializer (key: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer / value: myapps.PersonSerializer) is not compatible to the actual key or value type (key type: unknown because key is null / value type: java.lang.String). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:94)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:126)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamFlatMapValues$KStreamFlatMapValuesProcessor.process(KStreamFlatMapValues.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.runAndMeasureLatency(ProcessorNode.java:244)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:126)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:87)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:288)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to myapps.Person
    at myapps.PersonSerializer.serialize(PersonSerializer.java:1)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:154)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:98)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:89)
    ... 18 more
08:31:10,827 INFO  org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread     - stream-thread [json-enricher-0f8bc964-40c0-41f2-a724-dfa638923387-StreamThread-1] State transition from RUNNING to PENDING_SHUTDOWN
08:31:10,827 INFO  org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread     - stream-thread [json-enricher-0f8bc964-40c0-41f2-a724-dfa638923387-StreamThread-1] Shutting down
08:31:10,833 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer               - [Producer clientId=json-enricher-0f8bc964-40c0-41f2-a724-dfa638923387-StreamThread-1-producer] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.
08:31:10,843 INFO  org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread     - stream-thread [json-enricher-0f8bc964-40c0-41f2-a724-dfa638923387-StreamThread-1] State transition from PENDING_SHUTDOWN to DEAD
08:31:10,843 INFO  org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams                         - stream-client [json-enricher-0f8bc964-40c0-41f2-a724-dfa638923387] State transition from RUNNING to ERROR
08:31:10,843 WARN  org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams                         - stream-client [json-enricher-0f8bc964-40c0-41f2-a724-dfa638923387] All stream threads have died. The instance will be in error state and should be closed.
08:31:10,843 INFO  org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread     - stream-thread [json-enricher-0f8bc964-40c0-41f2-a724-dfa638923387-StreamThread-1] Shutdown complete
Exception in thread "json-enricher-0f8bc964-40c0-41f2-a724-dfa638923387-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in process. taskId=0_0, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000, topic=streams-plaintext-input, partition=0, offset=0
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:304)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:94)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:409)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.processAndMaybeCommit(StreamThread.java:957)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:832)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:767)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:736)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: A serializer (key: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer / value: myapps.PersonSerializer) is not compatible to the actual key or value type (key type: unknown because key is null / value type: java.lang.String). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:94)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:126)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamFlatMapValues$KStreamFlatMapValuesProcessor.process(KStreamFlatMapValues.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.runAndMeasureLatency(ProcessorNode.java:244)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:126)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:87)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:288)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to myapps.Person
    at myapps.PersonSerializer.serialize(PersonSerializer.java:1)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:154)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:98)
    at 
 org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:89)
    ... 18 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exception is because your `flatMapValues` produced value of type `String`. In your code you don't pass any `Produced` to `KStream::to` function so it tries to use default one (passed in properties), which in your case is `PersonSeder.class`.

Your values are of type `String`, but `PersonSeder.class` is used to serializatoin.

If you would like to split it you need something like this

```
KStream<String, Person> output = source
    .flatMapValues(person -> 
        Arrays.stream(person.getName().split(","))
            .map(name -> new Person(name, person.getAge()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

I've used following code with your serializer and with deserializer, that is symmetrical (also using a Gson) and it works

```java
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "app1");
    props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
    props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, PersonSerdes.class);
    final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    KStream<String, Person> source = builder.stream("input");
    KStream<String, Person> output = source
            .flatMapValues(person ->
                    Arrays.stream(person.getName()
                            .split(","))
                            .map(name -> new Person(name, person.getAge()))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    output.to("output");

    KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
    streams.start();
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
```

UPDATE 1:

According to your question regarding using json instead POJO, everything depends on your Sedes. If you use Generic Serdes you can serialize and deserialize to/from Json (Map)

Below is simple MapSerdes, that can be used for that and sample code of usage.

```java
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapSerdes implements Serde<Map<String, String>> {

    private static final Charset CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {}

    @Override
    public void close() {}

    @Override
    public Serializer<Map<String, String>> serializer() {
        return new Serializer<Map<String, String>>() {
            private Gson gson = new Gson();
            @Override
            public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {}

            @Override
            public byte[] serialize(String topic, Map<String, String> data) {
                String line = gson.toJson(data); // Return the bytes from the String 'line'
                return line.getBytes(CHARSET);
            }

            @Override
            public void close() {}
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Deserializer<Map<String, String>> deserializer() {
        return new Deserializer<Map<String, String>>() {
            private Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
            private Gson gson = new Gson();
            @Override
            public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {}

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
                Map<String,String> result = gson.fromJson(new String(data), type);
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            public void close() {}
        };
    }
}
```

Sample usage:
Instead name, depends on your map you can use different properties.

```
public class GenericJsonSplitterApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "app1");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, MapSerdes.class);

        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KStream<String, Map<String, String>> source = builder.stream("input");
        KStream<String, Map<String, String>> output = source
                .flatMapValues(map ->
                        Arrays.stream(map.get("name")
                                .split(","))
                                .map(name -> {
                                    HashMap<String, String> splittedMap = new HashMap<>(map);
                                    splittedMap.put("name", name);
                                    return splittedMap;
                                })
                                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        output.to("output");

        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
        streams.start();
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
    }
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same error : Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: A serializer (key: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer / value: myapps.PersonSerializer) is not compatible to the actual key or value type (key type: unknown because key is null / value type: java.lang.String). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to myapps.Person
 at myapps.PersonSerializer.serialize(PersonSerializer.java:1)

Comment: Code below :-`props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());        
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, PersonSeder.class);        
final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
KStream<String, Person> source = builder.stream("streams-plaintext-input");             
KStream<String, Person> output = source.flatMapValues(person -> Arrays.stream(person.getName().split(","))
                    .map(name -> new Person(name, person.getAge()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
output.to("streams-output");`

Comment: @Jana, Could you add code of your Serializer - `PersonSerializer`, I think there can be an issue?

Comment: `public class PersonSerializer implements Closeable, AutoCloseable, Serializer<Person> {
    private static final Charset CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    static private Gson gson = new Gson();
    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> map, boolean b) {
    }
    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String s, Person person) {
        // Transform the Person object to String
        String line = gson.toJson(person);
        // Return the bytes from the String 'line'
        return line.getBytes(CHARSET);
    }
    @Override
    public void close() {
    }}`

Comment: @Jana, I've added whole code, that I used, could you compare with yours?

Comment: @Jana, Did it help you?

Comment: I'm checking that. Will let you know

Comment: Now I'm able to execute. Eclipse was not taking my changes earlier. That's why I'm getting same error again and again. After refreshing snapshots, I'm able to see the output. Thanks

Comment: But I don't want to use POJO (here it's Person). Will I be able to get the required field (here it's "Name") from JSON array without using pojo??

Comment: @Jana, Could you share with more details. What would like to achieve?

Comment: @Jana, If it solve your problem, could you accept the answer?

Comment: Like, I'm getting a json array (specified above) from the kafka topic.Without using POJO, will I be able to achieve the same result? Since the data coming into input topic may change (e.g., a new column can be inserted in to the DB in future), and the POJO that I've written might not be having the new field and it will not pass the new field to the next topic(after transformation). You see my point?                               The challenging one is to do this `person.getName().split(",")`    without using POJO. Since `.getName()` is coming from POJO.

Comment: @Jana, I've update my answer with sample code, how to make it more generic. Make it short, everything depends on Serdes.

Comment: Thanks @wardziniak, What is `MapSerdes` here? Is it coming from any jar or customized sedes? how to get it?

Comment: @Jana, It is custom `Serdes`, that convert Json to `Map<String,String>`, and than you can use any property from json.

Comment: Hi @wardziniak, I've a question. Is there any way that we can increment a number for the records (as a result of the split?). Like, lets say after splitting a record(let's say A), it resulted into three records. Now I want to assign a number for these three records like 1,2,3. Once another record (B) is splitting into 4, now I've to assign 1,2,3,4 numbers. So far I'm able to increment the number for all the records, but not able to reset the number to start from 1 for the new records. Code in below comments

Comment: `static int i =0;
     public static void main(String[] args) {            
         KStream<String, Map<String, String>> source = builder.stream(inputTopic);
         KStream<String, Map<String, String>> output = source
                 .flatMapValues(map -> Arrays.stream((map.get(NAMES)).split(","))
                           .map(name -> {
                                      ............                                                                       
                                      i++;
           return ABC;                                 
output.to(OutPuttopic);`

Comment: @kuti, you have to do something like zipWithIndex.